# Juniper SRX Destination NAT for L2TP server

Tags: vpn, nat, juniper, juniper-junos, l2tp

I have a L2TP server on my LAN which I would like to access from WAN and there is a Juniper SRX standing between these two networks.
I've had some success with this post:
https://forums.juniper.net/t5/SRX-Services-Gateway/Destination-NAT-Port-Forwarding-Passthrough-for-VPN/td-p/264271

But while this allows me to connect to a PPTP server over port 1723, I can not reach the L2TP from outside the local network.
These are the relevant part of my configuration where 111.111.111.111 is the public of an interface in the untrust zone.:

destination nat:

```
destination {
        pool pptp-pool {
            address 192.168.2.48/32 port 1723;
        }
        pool p500 {
            address 192.168.2.48/32 port 500;
        }
        pool p4500 {
            address 192.168.2.48/32 port 4500;
        }
        pool p1701 {
            address 192.168.2.48/32 port 1701;
        }
        rule-set l2tp-vpn {
            from interface ge-0/0/6.0;
            rule r500 {
                match {
                    destination-address 111.111.111.111/32;
                    destination-port {
                        500;
                    }
                }
                then {
                    destination-nat {
                        pool {
                            p500;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            rule r1701 {
                match {
                    destination-address 111.111.111.111/32;
                    destination-port {
                        1701;
                    }
                }
                then {
                    destination-nat {
                        pool {
                            p1701;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            rule 4500 {
                match {
                    destination-address 111.111.111.111/32;
                    destination-port {
                        4500;
                    }
                }
                then {
                    destination-nat {
                        pool {
                            p4500;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            rule r1723 {
                match {
                    destination-address 111.111.111.111/32;
                    destination-port {
                        1723;
                    }
                }
                then {
                    destination-nat {
                        pool {
                            pptp-pool;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

security policy:

```
 from-zone untrust to-zone trust {
        policy vpn-access {
            match {
                source-address any;
                destination-address pd-nas;
                application any;
            }
            then {
                permit;
            }
        }
        policy untrust-to-trust {
            match {
                source-address any;
                destination-address any;
                application any;
                source-identity any;
            }
            then {
                deny;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

address book from trust zone

```
security-zone trust {
        address-book {
            address pd-nas 192.168.2.48/32;
        }
        host-inbound-traffic {
            system-services {
                all;
            }
            protocols {
                all;
            }
        }
```

How come this setup only works for the PPTP service? Do I need some additional setting to enable forwarding to the L2TP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrigth, I was wrong the issue isn't actually the configuration. I was using a router with a 4g card to test the VPN connection from an outside network. As it turns out, I can't connect to any vpn from that router, but it works from any other connection.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.